# How do we compress the number of entries in a table if the keys can start supporting "*" with a maximal match based retrieval

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, compression

Consider you have a table with 3 keys (A,B,C) and 1 value (D) that you would like to fetch. We will always ensure that there are no repeating rows with the same set of keys and different value. Something of this sort

```
A    | B    | C    | D
========================
a1   | b1   | c1   | d1
a1   | b1   | c2   | d1
a3   | b2   | c3   | d1
a2   | b3   | c2   | d2
a2   | b1   | c2   | d2
a2   | b2   | c3   | d3
```

(We would never have "a1,b1,c1,d1" and "a1,b1,c1,d2" at the same time in the table since this is conflicting)

This currently has 6 entries. Now suppose we start supporting the use of "star" (or "ALL") in the keys. When we try to fetch the value of D for a query set of keys, the maximal matching row is selected (maximal matching in the sense that the row where the maximum number of keys in A,B,C match exactly and the rest match with "star")

Sample resultant table (This is just one option, there are many other solutions as well)

```
A    | B    | C    | D
========================
*    | *    | *    | d1
a2   | *    | *    | d2
a2   | b2   | c3   | d3
```

This has only 3 entries which is half of the initial table. The compression would only increase as we start increasing the amount of data in the table and the number of keys etc.

Is there any algorithm that we can use to perform this kind of an optimization? Even a bruteforce/sub optimal solution is appreciated since I am currently clueless as to how this can be done.

Thanks!